# Edit the Job ID number of a pbs submitted job to achieve submission before other jobs in queue

Tags: linux, unix, hpc, pbs

Dear UNIX/PBS experts:

I am user of a UNIX HPC system (CentOS Linux 7 (Core),Linux 3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64) and I do not have any root privileges.
Various jobs have been submitted at an HPC system and almost all resources are being used.
Jobs from other users may run for weeks while my submitted job would finish in less than a day.
My goal is to run my job exactly after the first resources will be freed instead of waiting for
all other users to have their jobs finished.

My submitted job has a number qid 66005.pbs.
However the last job running at this moment has number 55004.pbs.
By checking the status of job: qstat 55005,
I obtain: qstat: Unknown Job Id 55005.pbs

Thus my question is whether it is possible to change the name of job 66005.pbs to 55005.pbs, and if this action will allow my job to run?
If yes, how  can this be achieved?
If not, are there any other solutions/alternatives for making sure that my jobs run before those ones of other users in queue?

Thank you very much for your help and any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The good thing about the computer system is that it is not human. It will be unfair to run your job (which clearly was submitted after other users) before other users and because of that "No" it is not possible to change your job-id.

You can work with your admin to move the job to a higher priority queue instead.